# Batteries in Series

Tags: battery-charging, battery-chemistry

i have 39 batteries of 33Ah 12V connected in series, i need to add 3 more batteries.
may i add 3 more batteries of 40Ah 12V in same series? 
what will happen technically?
kindly advise.

Comment: Cell balancing will be a must!

Comment: Worst case is a fire or explosion, though often not until you go to recharge.

Answer (score 15):

If you connect the 39 + 3 batteries to a load and that load is connected for a longish time you might find that the higher ampere-hour batteries are still running OK and trying to push current to the load but, the lower ampere-hour batteries are forced below their recommended lowest terminal voltage. In short, you might damage the lower ampere-hour batteries: -

[image]

Pictures taken from [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-11/practical-considerations-batteries/)

Comment: Congratulations on hitting 200k. That's a lot of useful help to a lot of people.

Comment: You may even reverse polarity of the smaller batteries if you keep running the large ones.

Answer (score 1):

Even with your 39 batteries, you should really be careful about discharging them too much, and you should probably check each of them separately for their voltage every now and then. Because in theory, even a 2V voltage drop on the whole ~470V battery pack can mean that a specific cell is seriously drained and can fail.

So basically nothing changes for you; you need a way to check the condition of each of the 42 batteries regularly to mitigate cells failing.

---

Well, you tag the question [battery-charging](/questions/tagged/battery-charging), so if that's an issue: **You should never charge cells of different capacity together.** Even the small chargers which charge 2 AA(A) batteries in series can perform badly because of cell imbalance. Charging in parallel goes in general better, because the more the battery is charged, the bigger its inner resistance to charging is and the less power the cell receives.

**However, do not charge 40 batteries in parallel!** Because even parallel charging has its limits and 40 car batteries are surely over the limit as the currents could become unbearable for any charger (it's easily 6A charging current for a single car battery, so here it could be hundreds of A). Especially, if the power source were weak, you'd probably be discharging the larger batteries in the set to charge the smaller ones at the beginning. (Thanks to user2813274 for pointing this out.)

Comment: Connecting them in parallel in order to charge can be dangerous at the battery levels involved here: 30+ AH batteries are huge and can create large currents (fusing wire levels) even at somewhat discharged states, especially since the 40AH will be at a much more charged state than the 33AH if they were discharged in series

Comment: @user2813274 Oh I didn't intent to imply that 40 of them is fine! I'll edit, thanks for this.